# Android ViewModel onChanged called when data isn't changed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have a `Fragment`, with a dynamic number of a custom views, consisting in an `EditText` and a `Button`. What I do is that every time the user types a price in the `EditText` and clicks the `Button`, I make an API request through a ViewModel, and my `Fragment` observes the `LiveData` in the `ViewModel`.

So far so good, when I use the first custom view. The problem comes on the second one (and the third), because the `onChanged()` method is apparently called even tho the data has not changed, and the second and the third custom views are listening to that data, so they change when they are NOT the ones triggering the data change (they receive the data change from the first one).

When the user clicks on the `Button`, the way I observe and fetch the price is this:

```
val observer = Observer<NetworkViewState> { networkViewState ->
            processResponse(networkViewState, moneySpent, coin, date)
        }
        boardingHistoricalPriceViewModel.coinDayAveragePrice.observe(this, observer)
        boardingHistoricalPriceViewModel.getDayAveragePrice(coin.symbol,
                addedCoinDatePriceView.selectedSpinnerItem, dateInMillis)
```

and what is happening is that the method `processResponse` gets called when the second custom view triggered the API request, but the result I receive is the one that `coinDayAveragePrice` has before the API response arrives (this is the value after the first API response from the first custom view has arrived).

This is part of my `ViewModel`:

```
val coinDayAveragePrice: MutableLiveData<NetworkViewState> = MutableLiveData()

fun getDayAveragePrice(symbol: String, currency: String, dateInMillis: Long) {
    coinRepository
            .getDayAverage(symbol, currency, "MidHighLow", dateInMillis)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe { coinDayAveragePrice.postValue(NetworkViewState.Loading()) }
            .subscribeBy(onSuccess = {
                coinDayAveragePrice.postValue(NetworkViewState.Success(it))
            }, onError = { throwable ->
                coinDayAveragePrice.postValue(NetworkViewState.Error(throwable.localizedMessage))
            })
}
```

`NetworkViewState` is just a `sealed class` meant as a wrapper for a response of an API request:

```
sealed class NetworkViewState {
class Loading : NetworkViewState()
class Success<out T>(val item: T) : NetworkViewState()
class Error(val errorMessage: String?) : NetworkViewState()
```

}

I have also tried to unsubscribe or to set the `coinDayAveragePrice` to null, but still I have the same problem.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please show some view model code.

Comment: One thing to note is that, whenever you subscribe to a live data, you'll immediately get the last value set on it, almost as if it's an rx Java BehaviorSubject.

Comment: post `LivaData<NetworkViewState> coinDayAveragePrice = ...` source code

Comment: @pskink updated the question and added some more code, thanks!

Comment: @AutonomousApps yes now I see, the problem here is that I'm subscribing again and thus I'm receiving the previous result right when subscribing, and what's messing things up

Comment: I honestly feel like you're misusing the framework a bit (no offense, it's easy to do!). Try describing exactly what you're trying to accomplish, in normal language, and then maybe the code to implement that will fall out naturally.

Comment: @AutonomousApps none taken ofc I really appreciate the help! indeed I might be misusing the framework, but in this case, how do people make a dynamic amount of requests through a ViewModel? creating a LiveData per request dynamically and observing them? P.S.: `SingleLiveEvent` class doesn't work either :(

Comment: Intuitively, I feel that your views should not be directly observing your live data. Since you have an arbitrary number of views hosted by a fragment, I think you should consider your fragment to be the controller and it should basically mediate between your views and your view model. Maybe another way to state it is your view model should expose an onClick function. Your views call that. Your fragment observes the live data and changes the state of all your views as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, without seeing your `ViewModel`, it's hard to be sure exactly what the problem is, but I think it's what I indicated in my comment. In that case, one solution is to use a different kind of `LiveData`. I got this basic idea from a blog post (don't remember the link :-/), but here's the class:

```
private const val TAG = "SingleLiveData"

/**
 * A lifecycle-aware observable that sends only new updates after subscription, used for events like
 * navigation and Snackbar messages.
 *
 * This avoids a common problem with events: on configuration change (like rotation) an update
 * can be emitted if the observer is active. This LiveData only calls the observable if there's an
 * explicit call to setValue() or call().
 *
 * Note that only one observer is going to be notified of changes.
 */
open class SingleLiveData<T> : MutableLiveData<T>() {

    private val pending = AtomicBoolean(false)

    @MainThread
    override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<T>) {
        if (hasActiveObservers()) {
            Logger.w(TAG, "Multiple observers registered but only one will be notified of changes.")
        }

        // Observe the internal MutableLiveData
        super.observe(owner, wrapObserver(observer))
    }

    @MainThread
    override fun observeForever(observer: Observer<T>) {
        if (hasActiveObservers()) {
            Logger.w(TAG, "Multiple observers registered but only one will be notified of changes.")
        }
        super.observeForever(wrapObserver(observer))
    }

    private fun wrapObserver(observer: Observer<T>): Observer<T> {
        return Observer {
            if (pending.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                observer.onChanged(it)
            }
        }
    }

    @MainThread
    override fun setValue(t: T?) {
        pending.set(true)
        super.setValue(t)
    }

    /**
     * Used for cases where T is Void, to make calls cleaner.
     */
    @MainThread
    fun call() {
        value = null
    }
}
```

Obviously, one problem with this is that it won't permit multiple observers of the same live data. However, if you require that, hopefully this class will give you some ideas.